# Problems with degradome sequencing results

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, rna-seq

I am a beginner in NGC analysis.
I have some cleaned degradome-seq files, FASTA format, provided by a company. I found out the length of reads in FASTA files are variable between 45-47nt.
I used Trimmomatic to remove adapters, but it removed all reads. How it could be possible?
Could the length of degradome-seq reads be more than 25nt?
Thanks.
[Fastqc report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahbrq.png)

Comment: You need to show us the code you used to trim the files. It is likely that you didn't set the minimum read length. I believe the default is something like 50 bp so all of you reads would have been removed

Comment: As they mentioned they are cleaned, I used CleaveLand4 to analyse, but the results were not consistent with previous data, so I used Trimmomatic. The code was used "java -jar trimmomatic-0.39.jar SE -phred33 X1-clean.fq.gz outpute.fq.gz ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-SE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:15"

Comment: Did you try running FastQC on the data before trimming? That could give you better idea of the quality of the reads. If all the reads are low quality then they could be getting removed by trimmomatic

Comment: Yes, I did. I checked the quality of raw data, I added a pic of the quality of fastq file. TCleaned ones are FASTA files and FastQC can't open it. But, it's ok to have 45-47nt reads in degradome files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.